# What is the difference between "schaffen" and "abschließen"?

Tags: meaning, difference

According to the dictionary, both, *schaffen* and *abschließen* mean  *to complete* and *to accomplish.* So what is the difference in usage between them?

Comment: The difference is from context where you would use one or the other.

Comment: I fail to understand what is closeworthy about this question.

Answer (score 3):

Hier ist der Versuch einer Erklärung:

**Etwas schaffen** heißt, eine Aufgabe erfolgreich (!) abzuschließen, wobei der Erfolg am Anfang nicht sicher war.*)

> Wirst du das schaffen? - Ich weiß nicht, ich glaube, die Aufgabe ist zu schwer für mich.

Do you think you can manage it? - I don't know, I think the task is too difficult for me.

> Hey, du hast es ja wirklich geschafft! Das hätte ich nicht gedacht!

Hey, you really did it! I did not believe you could!

**Abschließen** dagegen heißt einfach *zu Ende bringen*, *erledigen* - ohne dass der Erfolg am Anfang in Frage gestanden wäre.

> Kannst du diese Arbeit abschließen und dann mal rüberkommen?

Could you finalize this task, and then come here?

> Wenn du die Berechnung abgeschlossen hast, kannst du ja mal eine Pause machen.

As soon as you have finalized the calculation, you could take a break.

Man kann eine Arbeit theoretisch auch ohne Erfolg abschließen:

> Ich schließe die Arbeit an diesem Projekt jetzt ab. Das führt so oder so nicht zum Erfolg.

I will conclude my work on this project; it anyway will not have any result.

*) Note that this answer is not about the second meaning of *schaffen*, namely *create*.

Comment: What is the last sentence supposed to mean?

Comment: What last sentence? The last German one? Or the last English one? (If the English one: sorry for my amateurish English.)

Comment: Your totally fine! I would just like to help! But i mean both. "Das führt so oder so nicht zum Erfolg" und "it anyway will not have any result." Weiß ich nicht was du da sagen mochtest.

Comment: *So oder so* = anyway, either way, whatever you do about it, if you do it that way or the other way... Hence *Das führt so oder so nicht zum  Erfolg.* = *Whatever you do about it, you will not end up with any success in this project.* - Wird's damit klarer? - I will be happy seing a more appropriate way of expressing this in English.

Comment: Nicht zu vergessen, dass hier im Schwäbischen *schaffen* ein Synonym für *arbeiten* ist ;)

Comment: Müsste es dann nicht *It zom vrgässa* heißen?

Answer (score 0):

While the translations *complete* and *accomplish* are both correct for certain contexts, you should be aware of the common meanings of both **schaffen** und **abschließen**

**etw. schaffen** usually means *make sth*, *create* (although you should be aware of the more common *erschaffen*), and is often used in a figurative way - same as *make* in English (*manage*):

> Ich schaffe das nicht. - *I won't make it*.
>
> Schaffst du das?  - *Can you make it?*

**etw. abschließen** is derived from **(Ab)Schluss** which means *end*, *finish*, *finalization* etc. Beware that it also means *lock sth*.

> Wir müssen die Arbeit jetzt abschließen. - *We have to finish our work now.*

Answer (score 0):

Abschließen --> [finish something](http://www.dict.cc/german-english/etw+abschlie%C3%9Fen.html)

The focus is on the finishing

[Schaffen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schaffen) --> [accomplish](http://www.dict.cc/german-english/schaffen.html)

The focus is on accomplishing something.

The difference therefore is. You can finish something, like your shift at work without actually having accomplished anything.